# Login to HTTPS Page via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cant really seem to find this anywhere so I was wondering if you could help. I am trying to create a script which automatically logins to a HTTPS link via C#.

So essentially - I have a URL that contains a report I need to run daily but its behind a HTTPS login with username/password.

I am trying to create a script in C# which runs at X time, logins with username/password ? Any ideas?

Will love you long time!:)

Edit:---
OK now what if I want to save the *.txt file automatically to a database?

Comment: What do you mean by HTTPS login? HTTP Basic, Forms? Http-Digest auth?

Comment: you guys fking rock!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code that I wrote that logs into a website to send an SMS message:

```
private void sendMessage(SmsMessage message)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        CookieContainer cookies;
        string url = "http://www.xyzwebsite.com/";

        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                cookies = request.CookieContainer;



                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                String postData = "emailfrom="+credentials.Username+"&npa="+message.DestinationPhoneNumber.Substring(0,3)+"&exchange="+message.DestinationPhoneNumber.Substring(3,3)+"&number="+message.DestinationPhoneNumber.Substring(6)+"&body="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.MessageText)+"&submitted=1&submit=Send";
                byte[] data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                request.CookieContainer = cookies;

                stream.Close();

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                response.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client was unable to connect!");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            throw new SMSDeliveryException("Unable to deliver SMS message because " + e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

WebClient and NetworkCredential shoudl solve that for you, examples:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134945/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102605-1.aspx